# Unable to connect to the Microsoft Remote Debugging Monitor. A security package specific error occurred

Tags: visual-studio-2008, remote-debugging

I'm getting the following error when trying to attach to a remote debugging monitor running on another PC on our domain:

"Unable to connect to the Microsoft Visual Studio Remote Debugging Monitor named ''. A security package specific error occurred."

In addition, if you look on the remote machine you can see yourself as "connected" in the remote debugger window.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It took us a while to find this solution - I share it in the hope it saves others the same hassle

It seems to be related or limited to Windows XP and it seems to be also related to the settings on your domain - although exactly how we did not find out.

The solution was to install [this Hotfix](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/969442) from Microsoft. You will need to have Windows XP Service Pack 3 installed

This worked for us on four machines inside the same domain.

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing this! This helped me too. (Was trying to connect from VS 2005 on Win 2008 R2 x64 to a Win XP SP3 x86 and had the same message plus authentication errors in the event viewer security log on the Win 2008 machine)

Comment: Worked for me as well (VS 2010 on Windows 7 x64 to XP x32).  I spent four hours getting to this point, thanks for saving me countless more!  The problem seemed to be that the remote machine couldn't connect back to the windows 7 machine, which is why the debugging monitor showed the connection attempt but visual studio failed.  Don't know *why* it failed authentication back, however.  Perhaps its a problem in the kerberos auth module in XP.